# pandas to_csv comma were replace with a

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I want to write my data into `csv` file using `Pandas DataFrame` and my codes are:

```
>>> for _, dataframe in my_data.items():
        dataframe.to_csv('./my_file.csv', 'a')
```

But, problems are:

- when I open the `my_file.csv`, the comma "`,`" were replaced with 'a' like this:

  `1,2,3
  4,5,6`

  But it is:

  `1a2a3
  4a5a6`
- and I am using `append` mode in `to_csv` function, but the previous data were cleared, I am confused!

Comment: Is it not obvious that the issues are related? And you're telling CSV to use 'a' as the separator?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please refer to the API

your code is equal to

```
dataframe.to_csv('./my_file.csv', sep = 'a')
```

but you want

```
dataframe.to_csv('./my_file.csv', mode = 'a')
```

FYI:http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html

Answer (score 1):

The reason you're seeing an 'a' is because the second argument for `to_csv()` is the seperater. Change it to `dataframe.to_csv('./my_file.csv', ',')`, or omit the last part altogether `dataframe.to_csv('./my_file.csv')`

The `a` does not refer to append mode (I assume thats what you're talking about when you say append mode). Which means every time your loop runs, `my_file.csv` is being overwritten by the latest dataframe going through the loop.

I'm not sure what you want your resulting file(s) to look like, but you'll want to make sure you either use a different filename for each dataframe, or join all your dataframes together first and then write the new larger dataframe to a single csv file.